# DNS record with different ports

Tags: apache, dns, vps

I have a very cheap VPS with the IP `123.123.123.123` which listens on these ports: 7000, 7001, ... 7020. Apache listens on port 7010. Then I can access my website with http://123.123.123.123:7010.
As this is a shared IP, I cannot listen on port 80 myself with my VPS: I only have access to 7000 ... 7020.

I have registered a domain `mydomain1.com` by a domain provider and I'm using their nameservers.

**How to set up the DNS records such that any user going on http://www.mydomain1.com  will be transparantly directed to my website, with Apache ?**   (the browser will probably default to port 80, is that right?)

---

*I initially thought about such a DNS record:*

```
Name                TTL     Type    Priority    Content     
*.mydomain1.com     3600    A       0           123.123.123.123
```

*but then, I think I would have to access the website with http://www.mydomain1.com:7010 (which is not nice) and not http://www.mydomain1.com (which would be better).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot specify ports on DNS records. The only way to make it work as you expect is to have a reverse proxy running elsewhere ([nginx](https://www.nginx.com/), [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)), listening on port 80, and then forward traffic to your server.

Some useful information about HTTP proxying with nginx:

- [What is a reverse proxy?](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/)
- [Configuring nginx as a reverse proxy for apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache)

Comment: Correct; DNS has nothing to do with ports. A / AAAA records are purely hostname to IP address mappings, that's it.

Comment: What do you mean by reverse proxy listening on port 80?

Comment: I've included some information in the updated answer.

Comment: So does this mean that what I'm trying to do is impossible with my VPS only (listening on 7000 .. 7020)?

Comment: Yes. You can only access your site directly if you include the port in the URL.

Comment: Thanks @karliwson. Now this is closely linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600286/url-in-browsers-url-bar-changes-quickly-because-of-web-forwarding