# URL in browser's URL bar changes quickly because of web forwarding

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, dns, reverse-proxy

I have a VPS with the IP `123.123.123.123` and Apache listens there on port 7010. (I only have ports 7000 ... 7020 for myself).

I have registered a domain `mydomain1.com` by a domain provider and they offer a "web forwarding" :

```
Name                TTL     Type    Priority    Content        Forwards to
*.mydomain1.com     3600    A       0           212.20.xx xx   http://123.123.123.123:7010/
```

It works! Now when I write http://www.mydomain1.com in the browser URL bar, it automatically goes to http://123.123.123.123:7010/.

**Problem:** the browser URL bar only displays http://www.mydomain1.com for 0.5 seconds, and then displays http://123.123.123.123:7010/ instead, which is not nice in terms of user experience.

**How to keep the display http://www.mydomain1.com in the browser URL bar?**

Should I hack this with Javascript `history.pushState(...)`?

Should I do this in `.htaccess` with some `ReverseProxySomething`?

Another method?

Comment: `I only have ports 7000 ... 7020 for myself` - use a better host

Comment: @JaromandaX I have another dedicated server. But this is just a sandbox VPS for < 10$ per year, to learn how to do such things.
Anyway, I'm not sure I would have had access to port 80 with a for-me-only-IP with another VPS...

Comment: how about `mydomain1.com:7010`

Comment: Would work (with a simple DNS A record) but not nice...

Comment: it's all you've got

Comment: Well the website's HTML is succesfully loaded and displayed when I browse to `www.mydomain.com`, but the only problem is the change in the URL bar changes to 123.123.123.123:7010

Comment: "it works with" ... doesn't it change to `123.123.123.123:7010`

Comment: sorry, I meant `www.mydomain1.com:7010` - then you don't need web forwarding

Comment: I modified the comment

Comment: if you don't want a port number in the URL, use port 80 with http or port 443 with https - which you can't - so you'll have to live with the port number in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Going from "Default Forwarding" to "Framed" by the domain provider simply solved the problem.

[image]

The only drawback is that this is the resulting HTML, so this means it's some sort of hack...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<frameset frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="http://123.123.123.123:7010/" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
</frameset>
<noframes>
    <body>
        <a href="http://123.123.123.123:7010/">Click to be redirected</a>
    </body>
</noframes>
</html>
```

**Still looking for a better / cleaner solution!**